# Summarising and making percentages from speech in different languages in audio data

Tags: merge, dataset, percentage, mutate

I have a huge data set from a variety of families that captures speech in a variety of languages around their child. An example of my data is set out like the below:

| Duration(mSec) | Family ID | Language |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1000 | Family1. | French |
| 20000 | Family1 | English |
| 345000 | Family2. | Dutch |
| 47857 | Family2. | English |

I want to create a new data frame where I summarise the duration of all speech (in all languages) per family, then summarise the duration of speech per language in each family and then create a percentage based on these numbers e.g., `Family1 = French 30%, English 70%.(e.g. something like the below)`

| Family | Language | Duration | Percentage |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | English | 3454545 | 30% |
| 1 | French | 5878979 | 20% |
| 1 | Spanish. | 4545454 | 50% |
| 1. | All Languages | 2454253200 | 100% |

I am struggling to create such a code that would incorporate all of these instructions together rather than doing the steps separately.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!
Anna

I am struggling to create such a code that would incorporate all of these instructions together rather than doing the steps separately. I have been doing this separate using the below (this is to summarise the duration of English in each Lang):

```
Eng_observed <- Observed_Exposure %>%

subset(Language == 'English') %>%

group_by(Family, Language) %>%

summarise(sum(`Duration - msec`))
```

It gives me the result but then I have to do this separate for each language and then I end up with multiple data files and then manually join them together in excel. Would prefer to have the whole pipeline done in R.